# iOS MapKit: Code Refactoring with minor adjustment

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

With the Code below, when the location is moving, I'm getting multiple red Placemarks. Please see the picture below.

I'd like to remove the old Placemarks and update it with a new Placemark at the Current location. So at any given time there will only be one red Placemark.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)aManager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D regionCenter = newLocation.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(regionCenter, 400, 400);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

    [self reverseGeocode:newLocation];
}

-(void)reverseGeocode:(CLLocation *)location
{
    if (!geocoder)
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
    if (nil != error) {
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc]
         initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error translating coordinates into location",
                                         @"Error translating coordinates into location")
         message:NSLocalizedString(@"Geocoder did not recognize coordinates",
                                   @"Geocoder did not recognize coordinates")
         delegate:self
         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if ([placemarks count] > 0) {

        placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

        MapLocation *annotation = [[MapLocation alloc]init];
        annotation.street = placemark.thoroughfare;
        annotation.city = placemark.locality;
        annotation.state = placemark.administrativeArea;
        annotation.zip = placemark.postalCode;
        annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
  }];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you add another annotation, remove the previous ones

```
//remove all previous annotations
NSArray *previousAnnotations = self.mapView.annotations;
[self.mapView removeAnnotations: previousAnnotations];

//then add your new annotation here
placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
MapLocation *annotation = [[MapLocation alloc]init];
annotation.street = placemark.thoroughfare;
annotation.city = placemark.locality;
annotation.state = placemark.administrativeArea;
annotation.zip = placemark.postalCode;
annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Relevant apple documentation link for [`removeAnnotations:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW23)

If you want to only delete the previous annotation, store it as a property and remove it with a call to `removeAnnotation:`

In your `@interface` declare a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MapLocation *previousAnnotation;
```

Then in your code:

```
//remove the previous annotation if it exists
[self.mapView removeAnnotation: self.previousAnnotation];

//then add your new annotation here
placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
MapLocation *annotation = [[MapLocation alloc]init];
annotation.street = placemark.thoroughfare;
annotation.city = placemark.locality;
annotation.state = placemark.administrativeArea;
annotation.zip = placemark.postalCode;
annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

//set your property
self.previousAnnotation = annotation;
```

Comment: He can focus on removing only one annotation in case there are more annotation not involved in tracking the location.

Comment: Yeah, in that case he could just store the last annotation as a property and remove it before add new ones.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply.  @WojtekRutkowski is correct.  I would like to only remove the last annotation.  Can you please update the code?  Thanks

Comment: So all you want to do is to actually update the annotation. I think better and faster approach will be to update its variable, not to remove and then re-add. @danielbeard what do you think about that? I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can store annotation as property:

in header file `.h` or `@interface`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MapLocation *myAnnotation;
```

Then just update it by calling:

```
[myAnnotation setCoordinate:location.coordinate];
[myAnnotation setStreet:placemark.thoroughfare];
[myAnnotation setCity:placemark.locality];
...
```

Apple docs: [MKAnnotation/setCoordinate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKAnnotation/setCoordinate%3a)